# Vuejs Search filter

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a table that is presenting a list of items that I got using the following code:

```
interface getResources {
    title: string;
    category: string;
    uri: string;
    icon: string;
}
@Component
export default class uservalues extends Vue {

    resources: getResources[] = [];

    created() {
        fetch('api/Resources/GetResources')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<getResources[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.resources = data;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my table:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> All Resources</div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-12">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search" />
             </div>                        
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;">
             <table v-if="resources.length" class="table">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Resource</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     <tr v-for="item in resources">
                         <td><a v-bind:href="item.uri" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a></td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to implement a Search bar that filters the results for the user but I'm lost!

Any suggestions?

Comment: you want when you type for example `B` you will have items that begin with B?

Comment: Sorry! YESSSS that's what i want

Comment: i'm not familiar with typescript but i can give a solution using usual Vue code

Comment: That's great! i appreciate that

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `includes()` function of the `array` to search any position in a sentence or phrase.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        searchQuery: null,
        resources:[
            {title:"ABE Attendance",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
            {title:"Accounting Services",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
            {title:"Administration",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
            {title:"Advanced Student Lookup",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
            {title:"Art & Sciences",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
            {title:"Auxiliares Services",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
            {title:"Basic Skills",uri:"cccc.com",category:"c",icon:null},
            {title:"Board of Trustees",uri:"dddd.com",category:"d",icon:null}
        ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    resultQuery(){
      if(this.searchQuery){
      return this.resources.filter((item)=>{
        return this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v))
      })
      }else{
        return this.resources;
      }
    }
  }
 

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
         <strong> All Resources</strong></div>
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-12">
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>                        
            </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table v-if="resources.length" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>Resource</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="item in resultQuery">
                        <td><a v-bind:href="item.uri" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Based on this answer → [Vue.js search keyword in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276545/vue-js-search-keyword-in-array)

Comment: I know it's old, but what if I want to search not just title, but also other columns like uri, category etc in just one search input box?

Comment: Try this function:
filteredResources (){       
    if(this.searchQuery.length > 3){
        return this.resources.filter((item)=>{
          var columns = item.title + item.uri;
          return this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => columns.toLowerCase().includes(v));         
        })
        }
      }

Answer (score 11):

You could use `computed` property for this case, so, i created one called `filteredResources` which will be used in `v-for` loop, i had used dummy data, but you could keep your `resources` declared empty and call a promise function to fill it in `created` hook, check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7x7l6686j) if your are preferring single file component or the following code of you're using Vue via CDN

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery:'',
    resources:[
    {title:"aaa",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
     {title:"add",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
      {title:"aff",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
    {title:"bbb",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
    {title:"bdd",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
    {title:"bsb",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
    {title:"ccc",uri:"cccc.com",category:"c",icon:null},
    {title:"ddd",uri:"dddd.com",category:"d",icon:null}
    ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredResources (){
      if(this.searchQuery){
      return this.resources.filter((item)=>{
        return item.title.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
      })
      }else{
        return this.resources;
      }
    }
  }
 

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

   <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> All Resources</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <table v-if="resources.length" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Resource</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="item in filteredResources">
                                <td><a v-bind:href="item.uri" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Vue 3 version of a simple search.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    let searchText = ref('')
    const list = [
      'orange',
      'red',
      'blue',
      'black',
      'white'
    ]
    
    function filteredList() {
      return list.filter(data => data.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.value.toLowerCase()))
    }
    
    return {searchText, filteredList}
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchText">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="data in filteredList()" :key="data">
      {{ data }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS NAVBAR COMPONENTS**

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info display-6">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input v-model="search" class="form-control me-2"  id="inputGroup-sizing-lg" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>

<script>
import {mapActions} from "vuex"

export default{
    data(){
        return{
            search: ""
        }
    },
    watch:{
        search(newsearch) {
            this.filteredProducts(newsearch)
        }
    },
    methods:{
        ...mapActions([
            "filteredProducts"
        ])
    }
}
</script>
```

**THIS STORE.JS**

```
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        productsList: products,
        cartList: [],
        filtered: []
    },
    mutations:{
        filteredProducts(state, item) {
            if(item){
                state.filtered = products.filter((product) => product.Title.toUpperCase().includes(item.toUpperCase()))
                console.log(state.filtered);
            }
            if(state.filtered){
                console.log("state.filtered.lenght", state.filtered.lenght);
                state.productsList = [...state.filtered]
            }
        }
    },
    actions:{
        filteredProducts (context, item){
            context.commit('filteredProducts', item)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found easy way...using "@input function".. It's work for me!

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery:'',
      resources:[
        {title:"aaa",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
        {title:"add",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
        {title:"aff",uri:"aaaa.com",category:"a",icon:null},
        {title:"bbb",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
        {title:"bdd",uri:"bbbb.com",category:"b",icon:null},
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    
    getTextSearch: function(textSearch) {

        this.filteredResources= this.resources

        this.filteredResources= this.filteredResources.filter(item => {
            return item.uri.toLowerCase().includes(textSearch);
        });

    },

  }
 

})
```

Here html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

   <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> All Resources</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" @input="getTextSearch($event)" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <table v-if="resources.length" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Resource</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="item in filteredResources">
                                <td><a v-bind:href="item.uri" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```