# TypeScript/VueJS Filtered Search

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript2.0

I have a table that is presenting a list of items that I got using the following code:

MY table gets populate :

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:bold">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> 
    All Resources
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-12">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="" 
         placeholder="Search" />
     </div>                        
</div>
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in resources">

            this.resources = data;
        });
    }

}
```

I want to be able to type in the search bar and get results as I type in.

I tried something like this didn't work

```
 filteredResources() {
    if (this.sea
    } else {
        return this.resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: :) welcome back, i will try to answer your question with usual vue.js syntax

Comment: LOL, thanks!!! I know this should be the easiest thing ever, but I can figure it out, and when I think I got it, in my Input (search bar) I'm getting [object][object]

Comment: i don't see the difference between this question and the last one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs Search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558770/vuejs-search-filter)

Comment: @HusamIbrahim yes i see that