# TypeError: this.results.filter is not a function in searchbox Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been struggling to implement a search function in VueJS 2.0.

I'm trying to copy this code that I got in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558770/vuejs-search-filter) but couldn't implement it.

I don't know where I made a mistake.

The result is an object where the json data is stored.

```
    <template>
  <section>
    <b-form-input v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search user by full name"></b-form-input>
    <div v-for="result in filteredResources" :key="result.id">
      <td>{{result.LONG_D}}</td>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: "",
      results: {},
      search: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getDiseases();
  },
  methods: {
    getDiseases: function() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:9000/api/diseases/")
        .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  },
  computed: {
    /* Search Bar */
    filteredResources() {
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        return this.results.filter((item) => {
          return item.title.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
        });
      } else {
        return this.results;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is the error

> TypeError: this.results.filter is not a function

This is the json that will be stored in **result:{}**
[image: json]

Comment: You can't call `.filter` on an object

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: `Object.keys(this.results).filter((key) => this.results[key].title.startsWith(this.searchQuery))` would work presumably.

Comment: It doesn't work though

Comment: Is `response.data` an array? If so, initialise your `results` data property to be the same type, ie `results: []`

Comment: @Phil an object so I tried to do, results: {}

Comment: You may also find it's _"not working"_ because you're trying to put `<td>` elements within a `<div>`. Vue does some rudimentary HTML validation for things like this and will not render invalid `<table>` markup

Comment: @Phil hi, i edited the question and added an image of my data

Comment: @Phil I tried to follow the code of ohgodwhy and got new error with ReferenceError: key is not defined

Comment: None of those data entries has a `title` or `id` property so what is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Phil I want them to be searched in a searchbox

Comment: @Phil search by LONG_D

Comment: @Phil yeah, I  changed the title to LONG_D and it worked somehow. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend working directly with the `results` array from your AJAX response.

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  searchQuery: '',
  results: []
}),
async created () {
  let { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:9000/api/diseases/")
  this.results = data.results
},
computed: {
  filteredResources() {
    let normalizedQuery = this.searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase()
    if (normalizedQuery.length) {
      return this.results.filter(({ LONG_D }) => 
          LONG_D.toLowerCase().startsWith(normalizedQuery))
    }
    return this.results
  }
}
```

You should also fix your template

```html
<div v-for="result in filteredResources">
  <p>{{result.LONG_D}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Phil, why use async? I don't know asnyc and all the code you've written.

Comment: @Vin because it's shorter and I hate scrolling . It's the same as `axios.get(...).then(response => (this.results = response.data.results))`