# VueJS computed filter function not working

Tags: vue.js

So I'm trying to implement the functionality explained here [Vuejs Search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558770/vuejs-search-filter/52560430)
but the function inside the computed doesn't seem to work, not even logging anything, here's  my code:

```
...
<a-layout-header style="background: #fff; padding: 0">
    <a-input-search 
      placeholder="Search everything" 
      style="width: 200px; marginLeft: 20px" 
      v-model="searchData"
    />
    <a-button type="primary" style="marginLeft: 20px">
      + New
    </a-button>
</a-layout-header>
...
data() {
  return {
    data: json,
    collapsed: false,
    item_key: 1,
    searchData: ''
  };
},
computed: {
  searchResult() {
    if (this.searchData) {
      return this.data.filter((item) => {
        return this.searchData.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => 
                  item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v));
        })
    } else {
      return this.data;
    }
  }
},
```

**Edit: the data that is filtering it's being passed as a prop to a child component, and there I have a ant-design table that gets it:**

```
<a-table
  v-if="this.item.toString() === '1'"
  :columns="columns"
  :row-key="record => record.guid"
  :data-source="normalData"
  :pagination="pagination"
  :row-selection="rowSelection"
>
</a-table>
```

Comment: First, did you omitted your "data" with that "json" statement for brevity?
Do you actually call your computed somewhere?

Comment: No, my data is actually a json which im imported from a file data.json

Comment: And im quite new to Vue, do I need to call computed somewhere in the vue file?

Comment: I'm just wondering how you debugged your computed value. It looks fine from my point of view.
Just add `{{ searchResult }}` somewhere in your template to see what's the value computed! Or you can use the chrome "vuejs devtools" extension to debug your Vuejs app

Comment: Also, you can try with a dummy "data" object (not from a json file, just create the object yourself in the component) to check if you really have data.

Comment: The data is for sure ok, I logged it out and its complete, the problem that I am still facing is that the function searchResult is not executing at any point of time, no matter if I change the input filter

Comment: You were actually right that I need to call the function in the computed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should implement the search filter:

```html
...
<div>
    <input
      placeholder="Search everything" 
      v-model="searchData"
    >
    <div v-for="(item,index) in filteredList" :key="index">
      {{ item.title }}
    </div>
</div>
...
data() {
  return {
    data: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'First item',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Second item',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Third item',
  },
],
    searchData: ''
  };
},
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    const filter = this.searchData.trim().toUpperCase();
    return filter ? this.data.filter(item =>
    {
      return item.title.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    }) : this.data;
  }
},
```

Comment: So this is my fault that I didnt specify the whole functionality, the data that I am filtering it's actually passed as a prop to a child component, and there I have an ant-design table which gets this data

Comment: You can change the template to use the AntDesign table - it will not affect the JavaScript code in any way. Just send the `filteredList` to the table.