# Vue.js Filter working locally, but not on server

Tags: vue.js, filter

I am fairly new to Vue and I know, that I am probably not following best practice on how to structure code. However, this is really just quick and dirty and I stumbled over a strange situation.

A piece of code to filter down an array (kind of live-search) works on my local MAMP server, but not on my NAS-based webserver.

This is the piece of code:

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#recipe-app-start',
        data: {
            searchQuery: null,
            recipes: [],
        },
        filters: {
            recipeUrl(id) {
                return 'recipe.php?id=' + id;
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            fetch(globalConfig.restServer + 'recipes')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    this.recipes = data;
                    console.log(this.recipes);
                })
        },
        computed: {
            // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558770/vuejs-search-filter
            resultQuery() {
                if (this.searchQuery) {
                    return this.recipes.filter((item) => {
                        return this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(v => (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v) || item.description.toLowerCase().includes(v)))
                    })
                } else {
                    return this.recipes;
                }
            }
        },
    })

</script>
```

The only difference is the URL to the rest server (which is also changed to the same server).
The array initially populates, but when I try to type into the respective search field, locally it works and filters out irrelevant entries, while on the server it just raised an error in the console:

```
(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue:634
logError @ vue:1893
globalHandleError @ vue:1888
handleError @ vue:1848
Vue._render @ vue:3553
updateComponent @ vue:4067
get @ vue:4478
run @ vue:4553
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue:4311
(anonymous) @ vue:1989
flushCallbacks @ vue:1915
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue:1942
nextTick @ vue:1999
queueWatcher @ vue:4403
update @ vue:4543
notify @ vue:745
reactiveSetter @ vue:1070
proxySetter @ vue:4630
input @ VM237:3
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue:1863
invoker @ vue:2188
original._wrapper @ vue:7547
vue:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
    at (index):114
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at (index):114
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Vue.resultQuery ((index):113)
    at Watcher.get (vue:4478)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue:4583)
    at Proxy.computedGetter (vue:4832)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at createFunction (vue:11649), <anonymous>:3:561)
    at Vue._render (vue:3551)
logError @ vue:1897
globalHandleError @ vue:1888
handleError @ vue:1848
Vue._render @ vue:3553
updateComponent @ vue:4067
get @ vue:4478
run @ vue:4553
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue:4311
(anonymous) @ vue:1989
flushCallbacks @ vue:1915
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue:1942
nextTick @ vue:1999
queueWatcher @ vue:4403
update @ vue:4543
notify @ vue:745
reactiveSetter @ vue:1070
proxySetter @ vue:4630
input @ VM237:3
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue:1863
invoker @ vue:2188
original._wrapper @ vue:7547
vue:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue:634
logError @ vue:1893
globalHandleError @ vue:1888
handleError @ vue:1848
Vue._render @ vue:3553
updateComponent @ vue:4067
get @ vue:4478
run @ vue:4553
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue:4311
(anonymous) @ vue:1989
flushCallbacks @ vue:1915
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue:1942
nextTick @ vue:1999
queueWatcher @ vue:4403
update @ vue:4543
notify @ vue:745
reactiveSetter @ vue:1070
proxySetter @ vue:4630
input @ VM237:3
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue:1863
invoker @ vue:2188
original._wrapper @ vue:7547
vue:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
    at (index):114
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at (index):114
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Vue.resultQuery ((index):113)
    at Watcher.get (vue:4478)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue:4583)
    at Proxy.computedGetter (vue:4832)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at createFunction (vue:11649), <anonymous>:3:561)
    at Vue._render (vue:3551)
```

Any ideas of the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Do you fetch same data when you are locally and from NAS-based webserver ?

It seems that there is a problem when trying to use toLowerCase function. This is probably because of an `item.title` or `item.description` that returns null.

Comment: Yes, the REST server is copied over 1:1 and also the database.

Comment: I am so stupid. I found the error: apparently I added one additional entry on the server v version. And that one indeed contained one row with a null "value" in description - that was causing the issue... Now I know, that I need to cater for this as well...

Comment: Well, that's how we gain experience ! ahah

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid. I found the error: apparently I added one additional entry on the server v version. And that one indeed contained one row with a null "value" in description - that was causing the issue... Now I know, that I need to cater for this as well...